# How to upgrade within a LTS release (not to a new one)?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, lts, do-release-upgrade

I have an old 12.04.2 Ubuntu server. I want to update it to 12.04.5. But `do-release-upgrade` would upgrade to 14 LTS.

What do I have to do in order to update only within my LTS release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by simply keeping your system up-to-date with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

No special upgrade techniques are necessary if you already using 12.04.